# How to display the Image From the retrieved image URL in the DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

the SS of my current App

[image: 1]

I set all the codes to retrieve the information from the SQL table , now i only need to convert the retrieved image URL to Image in the DataGridView

**here is the codes am using now :**

```
    namespace LamasoDemo
    {
             public partial class FormOrders : Form
             {
                public FormOrders()
                 {
                   InitializeComponent();
                   FillGridView();
                 }

    
    void FillGridView()
    {
        List<Products> productsList = new List<Products>();
        Products products = new Products();
        productsList = products.GetProducts();
        dataGridViewProducts.DataSource = productsList;
    }
```

**and on the class here is the codes :**

```
public class Products
    {
       
       public string? Image { get; set; }
       
    

string connectionString = "Data Source=AHMEDBABAJAN;Initial Catalog=Lamaso1;Integrated Security=True;Trust Server Certificate=true";


    
    public List<Products> GetProducts()
    {
        List<Products> ProductsList = new List<Products>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        string selectSQL = "select  Image Status From GetProductsData";
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr != null)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Products Products = new Products();

                
                Products.Image = dr["Image"].ToString();
                
                ProductsList.Add(Products);
            }
        }

        return ProductsList;

    }
```

Anyone have any idea on how to show the image ? from URL

Comment: It's your `Products` (should be single) class that needs to retrive the Image when you pass the URI to it -- You should probably avoid naming a Property `Image`, when it actually stores the `ImageUri`. When you do that, it's also easier to retrieve a thumbnail of the real image, then show the original (larger) image when / if required

Comment: sorry i didn't understand , i just upload SS image , please check it out

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is using an unbound `DataGridViewImageColumn`, then you can handle `CellFormatting` event and load the image.

In the following example, I've handled the `CellFormatting` event, considering the following points:

- The code loads images lazily, once requested in `CellFormattings`.
- It stores image in the cell value, to avoid loading it again.

[image]

To try the code, create a Form, drop a DataGridView on it and use the following code:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(
        "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; " +
        "WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");

    //Load data
    var data = GetData();

    //Set up dataGridView 
    dgv1.RowTemplate.Height = 100;
    dgv1.DataSource = data;
    dgv1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewImageColumn()
    {
        Name = "ImageColumn",
        HeaderText = "Image",
        ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom,
        Width = 150
    });
    dgv1.CellFormatting += dgv1_CellFormatting;
}
private async void dgv1_CellFormatting(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex < dgv1.NewRowIndex &&
        dgv1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "ImageColumn")
    {
        var item = (DataRowView)dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
        var uri = item.Row.Field<string>("ImageUri");
        if (e.Value == null || e.Value == DBNull.Value)
        {
            dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                .Cells["ImageColumn"].Value = await DownloadImage(uri);
        }
    }
}
DataTable GetData()
{
    var data = new DataTable();
    data.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    data.Columns.Add("ImageUri", typeof(string));
    data.Rows.Add("Lorem", $"https://picsum.photos/300/200?1");
    data.Rows.Add("Ipsum", $"https://picsum.photos/300/200?2");
    data.Rows.Add("Dolor", $"https://picsum.photos/300/200?3");
    data.Rows.Add("Sit", $"https://picsum.photos/300/200?4");
    data.Rows.Add("Amet", $"https://picsum.photos/300/200?5");
    return data;
}

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
async Task<Image> DownloadImage(string uri)
{
    return Image.FromStream(await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(uri));
}
```

Run the code and see the result.

You should also take care of disposing the images:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
    if (!e.Cancel)
    {
        DisposeImages();
    }
}
void DisposeImages()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv1.Rows)
    {
        if (!row.IsNewRow)
        {
            var value = row.Cells["ImageColumn"].Value;
            row.Cells["ImageColumn"].Value = null;
            if (value is Image)
                ((Image)value).Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

You may also want to modify the code and handle cases when the image could not be downloaded.

Comment: It looks like the post answers your question. Did you forget to accept the answer?